# button= appended as last param in elasticsearch search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, get, slim-lang

I'm using elasticsearch and have run into a weird issue. I have a form for users to submit their search but for some reason, when a user enters their query and then clicks on the submit button, the last parameter is button=
See bellow:

http://lvh.me:3000/products?utf8=(checkmark)&q=tree&button=

Here is the form. Not sure if this is an issue with the form, rails, or elastic search.

```
section.search
      = form_tag main_app.products_path, method: :get
        = text_field_tag 'q', nil, placeholder: t(:search)
        = button_tag type: 'submit'
          = icon('fa fa-search')
```

(edit) HTML:

```
<form action="/products" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
                <input type="text" name="q" id="q" placeholder="Search"><button name="button" type="submit">
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What does the HTML code of the form this produces look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<button name="button" type="submit">` doesn't have any `value` attribute (i.e. the default output for `button_tag`), hence when the form is submitted, `button=` is appended like any other named parameter of your form. If you don't want that parameter to be submitted, you should probably add an empty name into `button_tag`, i.e.

```
button_tag type: 'submit', name: ''
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! (for others reading, just have to add a comma after 'submit'.